# Why svg in <g-image> is resized changing aspect?

Tags: css, vue.js, svg, flexbox, gridsome

I have the following simple component:

```
<template>
    <div class='d-flex justify-content-center'>
        <g-image src='~/assets/bitcoin.svg' width='36' height='36' />
        <h2 class='mx-2'>{{ block_count }}</h2>
        <g-image src='~/assets/bitcoin.svg' width='36' height='36' />
    </div>
</template>
```

(the `.svg` is around 64 in width and height)

Which in small widths gives nice square images:

[image]

but as soon as I start increasing the window size in width it streches out the `.svg`

[image]

I've tried to use a couple of `g-image`'s [`fit` parameters](https://gridsome.org/docs/images/#fit-options) but with no luck.

What am I not getting here?

**EDIT** Live URL to showcase [bitcoin-blocks-info-site.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com](http://bitcoin-blocks-info-site.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com)

**EDIT**

It seems that when I apply `b-container` scaffolding then the problem goes away:

```
<template>
    <b-container>
        <b-row>
            <b-col class='d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center'>
                <g-image src='~/assets/bitcoin.svg' width='36' />
                <h2 class='mx-3 d-inline'>{{ block_count }}</h2>
                <g-image src='~/assets/bitcoin.svg' width='36' />
            </b-col>
        </b-row>
    </b-container>
</template>
```

Comment: Any way to add a live URL?... For not SVG files (png/jpeg) this also happens?

Comment: @EzraSiton Live URL for now: http://bitcoin-blocks-info-site.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/